# Accessing internal wordpress site from the web

Tags: static-website

My webserver(WordPress) is running Apache on localhost port 80 with dedicated public IP.
On the Firewall I have configured a SNAT rule:

```
HTTP policy - (From Anyone on the web) > (using public IP) > (send traffic to Internal IP)).
```

I can confirm SNAT works to an extend. I can access the wordpress page through the public IP. However, the site doesn't load properly. CSS and images are gone and the whole layout is decremented:

When trying to /wp-admin, the external user sees "localhost/xxx" and connection is lost.

[Image 1 and 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ENEh.jpg)

Just to mention, my site runs Apache24 with phpmyadmin, php7.4, MySQL and WordPress 5.4.

If any info is needed let me know.

Edit:
phpmyadmin is accessible and I can login without any problems. This must indicate that the issue is a wordpress configuration. Nevertheless, I hope someone can help :-)

[Image: phpmyadmin access via public IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpXSK.jpg)

Comment: Can you re-upload your images using the built in image uploader rather than pasteboard.com? They're not loading

Comment: I've uploaded the images on imgur. They work now :)

Comment: [Check to see if your `site_url` and/or `home` settings set to `localhost`.](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/)  If they are, try changing them to use your dedicated IP address instead.

Comment: That wouldn't work. The whole problem is, even if you manage to access the front page of yourd WordPress, the moment you click something a new path is created. For example localhost/xxx or publicIP/xxx. This (in my case) will result in connection loss. Anyway I answered my own question. The trick was very simple but unfortunately I was too naive to follow other peoples "way-of-doing-things"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to fix it by changing both SiteURL and homeURL to being the exact same. Now I've finally added an A-record in my DNS so the sites uses its own URL. Works like a charm :)

Im not sure why but I've seen others place "http://..." for SiteURL and "http://www..." for homeURL. However, this wouldn't work in my case even. Hope it can help other who face the same problem.

Comment: You need a DNS record for both www.example.com and example.com because they are seen as different entiries. You can also use CNAME for www and point it at example.com although that requires additional lookups. The A Record is a better option.

Comment: Would a URLforward work too? because im struggling to redirect www requests to http hmm

Comment: Yes, a URL forward should work as long as both www. and example.com exist in the DNS. If you mean URL forward as in CNAME which forwards www to example.com or visa versa. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Perfect thank you. My A record and URL forward works now. Had to wait up to 24 hours for the DNS server to register changes :-)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. :)